# Unable to Edit GPOs Despite Being Member of Requisite Groups

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

My user is a member of Domain Admins, Enterprise Admins, and Group Policy Creator Owners. However, I'm trying to edit a GPO that is in place which will add a domain to the trusted sites for our domain and the list appears completely grayed out when I try to add a domain to that list (the box where I need to type in a new website to add to the zone is completely gray).

I'm running Windows Server 2008 but at the Windows Server 2003 functional level.

Not really sure where to go from here...anybody?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make changes to other policies?  Are you talking about the  trusted sites for IE?

Comment: I can make changes to other policies. And yes, I'm talking about trusted sites for IE, sorry for not being more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I was trying to edit things under the User Configuration but it was actually configured under the Computer Configuration. A full description of the solution is below:

You will need to configure the group policy under Computer Configuration instead of User Configuration.

Computer Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Internet Explorer

Sites to Zone Assignment List
1-Local, 2-Trusted, 3-Internet, 4-Restricted

When you configure the settings under User Configuration/Internet Explorer Maintenance, you are setting the DEFAULT settings for the computer (which is usually helpful when you are creating an image of the workstation). It does NOT enforce the settings after the fact.